# intellij 2017.2 System.setProperty 'class' or 'interface' expected

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I've got a typical Class for launching webbrowsers in my WebDriver tests. I use IntelliJ and since version 2017.2 it underlines (red line): "webdriver.gecko.driver" or "webdriver.chrome.driver", with explanation:   'class' or 'interface' expected.
Could You tell me why?

My class contains:

```
package com.qa.commonhelper;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BrowserFactory {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browserName, String url) {
        if (browserName.equals ("firefox") && osDetector ().equals ("Linux")) {
            System.setProperty ("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browserName.equals ("chrome") && osDetector ().equals ("Linux")) {
            System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver");
            driver = new ChromeDriver ();
        } else if (browserName.equals ("firefox") && osDetector ().equals ("Windows")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browserName.equals ("chrome") && osDetector ().equals ("Windows")) {
            System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver ();
        }
        driver.get (url);
        driver.manage ().window ().maximize ();
        driver.manage ().timeouts ().implicitlyWait (6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return BrowserFactory.driver;
    }

    public static String osDetector () {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        if (os.contains("win")) {
            return "Windows";
        } else if (os.contains("nux") || os.contains("nix")) {
            return "Linux";
        } else {
            return "Other";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does IntelliJ flag the row or is this actually a hard compilation error? IntelliJ can be configured to flag things as errors when the Java compiler really wouldn't care. If you hover over the error in intelliJ does it suggest an improvement or a change?

Comment: Also - consider posting this code block to codereview.stackexchange.com as a new question. I see some improvements that could make this code easier to maintain even though it isn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: I would try moving your "exe"s to a different folder outside of src.  How is your resource folder marked?  This could be causing the error.

Comment: I've got drivers for Linux, eg. geckodriver (file without any extension) and it is indicated as an error as well as files with .exe extension.